# 2 Branches share one folder for images?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I am building a Laravel/ ReactJS application, I have 3 branches:
`-> master (production)   -> develop (staging)   -> cms (content management system)`

When on the `cms` branch you can change the content on the site, add new images, categories, etc.. And everything is updated in the database, and then my website resides in the `develop` branch which is connected to the same DB, and it is reading the updated files from there, however, the issue that I have is, because when I upload images in the admin panel (on the `cms` branch) they are uploaded in public/uploads folder, but because it is different branches when I go to develop, I cannot see that folder...

One manual solution is that every time I finish with making changes to the site from the `cms` branch I manually copy the uploads folder, change the branch and paste it in the `develop` branch. Is there any way to kind of both branches share the same upload folder, or maybe somehow when I push the changes to the `cms`" branch it just copies the uploads folder on the `develop` branch.

I do not have a lot of experience with git branching, so please forgive me if what I am talking about makes no sense, and correct me accordingly.. Thank you!

Comment: At a quick glance : I would suggest to represent your `cms` content as a directory in your repo (not as a branch), which will have a version on master and a version on develop. I'm not sure I understood all your constrains, though.

Comment: The constraints are, that I have an `uploads` folder located in the root, and in this folder are all uploads that have been made from the admin dashboard, however, because `cms` and `develop` are different branches, when I switch to `develop` I cannot see the uploaded files, because it is a different branch..

Comment: Do you mean : on your production website, the `uploads` folder, which may be uploaded to using the admin interface of the website, is versioned and pushed to your `cms` branch ?